# Unsupported Media Type error in SoapUI

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, soapui

I checked all of the this kind of problems in stackoverflow that you met. But I couldn't match with mine.

- So, i wanna test my webservice with SoapUI.
- In my wsdl link there is no type definiton for inputs (it says just
  string. it wants loginName, userName and password).
- And also I have real inputs to check it, but on the right side of my
  Request window there is always this sentence: "The server cannot
  service the request because the media type is unsupported." in every
  test.
- I checked my Raw tabs, my content-types are text/xml;charset=UTF-8
  and I think it should be like this too.
- And also during the test, it is using the first SOAP.

This problem can be about what? My web browser? My client? My internet settings? What should i do?

Note: I tried trial webservices that i found from the webservicex.net, i could test them without error...

Comment: When you look at the raw tab of the tab on the right, do you see an xml? What do you mean by using the first SOAP?

Comment: No, I don't. I only see that error..

Comment: is this a service you built or is this something you are testing for a client? I have been reading up on post about this error and all of them seem to point towards a problem with the service.